# Referencing External Library project classes or lib file from my project ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to divide some class files into the project library and i need to reference that library to my project.

Example: MyProjectXcode will be divided into MyProjectXcode, DatabaseLibraryXcode and NetworkLibraryXcode three different xcode projects, but DatabaseLibraryXcode, NetworkLibraryXcode are the library projects.

MyProjectXcode needs to reference the library classes. I tried by including the library inside MyProjectXcode it is working. But i dont want to drag the library into my project. I just need to reference those files. I tried adding those project path in user header paths didn't worked. Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

Open Project Settings>>Build Phases>>Link Binary With Libraries>> scroll down click on '+' sign and add Libraries from finder.

Links for creating static libraries and linking inside XCode Proj.

1st [Link](http://www.voidasterisk.org/post/4232502037/how-to-create-a-ios-static-library-and-link-via-xcode)
2nd [Link](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/)

Comment: I added the lib.a file through Link Binary With Libraries from inside DerivedData. I tried to import the class which is inside the lib. Now it is showing cannot find the class .h

Comment: what u can do is copy all libraries .a in ur project folder from finder and then try Link Binary With Libraries , taking finder to ur project folder

Comment: I copied the libSampleProj.a into my project folder and tried linking through Link Binary With Libraries. Now #import "SampleProj.h", #import <SampleProj.h> and #import <libSampleProj/SampleProj.h> all are showing file not found.

Comment: Is i need to copy the .h files too?. I am not understanding the concept of creating the static library and linking. Do u know any detailed link which describes creating and adding the static libraries.?